# How to save interpolated data in a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I would like to save the newly interpolated grid in a CSV file with the structure: Lat, Long, Value.

The code I have written so far looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pykrige.kriging_tools import write_asc_grid
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt


def get_data(df):
    return {
        "lons": np.array([6.47, 4.8, 1.94]),
        "lats": np.array([46.37, 43.9, 47.83]),
        "values": np.array([-29.5, -27.6, -32.5]),
    }

def extend_data(data):
    return {
        "lons": np.concatenate([np.array([lon-360 for lon in data["lons"]]), data["lons"], np.array([lon+360 for lon in data["lons"]])]),
        "lats":  np.concatenate([data["lats"], data["lats"], data["lats"]]),
        "values":  np.concatenate([data["values"], data["values"], data["values"]]),
    }

def generate_grid(data, basemap, delta=1):
    grid = {
        'lon': np.arange(-180, 180, delta),
        'lat': np.arange(np.amin(data["lats"]), np.amax(data["lats"]), delta) # dont extrapolate towards the poles
    }
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = np.meshgrid(grid["lon"], grid["lat"])
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = basemap(grid["x"], grid["y"])
    return grid

def interpolate(data, grid):
    Ok = OrdinaryKriging(
        data["lons"],
        data["lats"],
        data["values"],
        variogram_model='exponential',
    )
    return Ok.execute("grid", grid["lon"], grid["lat"])

def inter_todf(interpolation, grid):
    dfl = pd.DataFrame({
         'latitude': grid['x'].reshape(-1),
         'longitude': grid['y'].reshape(-1),
         'value': interpolation.reshape(-1)
    });
    return(dfl)

base_data = get_data()
grid = generate_grid(base_data, basemap, 1)
extended_data = extend_data(base_data)
interpolation, interpolation_error = interpolate(extended_data, grid)
dfl = inter_todf(interpolation, grid)
dfl.to_csv('foo')
```

With this code I get the following output (print(dfl)):

```
           latitude     longitude     value
0      5.650097e+06  8.681598e+05 -7.094071
1      5.713078e+06  8.681598e+05 -7.099389
2      5.776060e+06  8.681598e+05 -7.104715
3      5.839042e+06  8.681598e+05 -7.110051
4      5.902023e+06  8.681598e+05 -7.115394
...             ...           ...       ...
57235  2.684171e+07  1.687378e+07 -8.435601
57236  2.689803e+07  1.687378e+07 -8.449231
57237  2.695434e+07  1.687378e+07 -8.462931
57238  2.701066e+07  1.687378e+07 -8.476702
57239  2.706697e+07  1.687378e+07 -8.490544
```

However, it is noticeable that the Lat or Long values are much too high. For example, Lat should only have values between +90 and -90 degrees and Long between +180 and -180. What am I doing wrong?

The Example my "solution" based on:
[Is there a way to save interpolated values to a python dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576909/is-there-a-way-to-save-interpolated-values-to-a-python-dataframe)

Comment: What did you try already? WHY did it not work? You talk about this beeing asked somewhere else already. WHY did the solutions proposed there not work for you?

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you, you might want to post an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which only contains the most cirtical code.

Comment: I Think this code contain only the essential snipes

Comment: Ok. But the code where you try to save to the .csv file ist missing. Please include the part which gives you the "All Arrays must be the same length" error. You could also remove unneccessary comments like the todos (and add others where helpfull).

Comment: Which variable produces the output you added? Is it the dfl? Please add that information to the question. Also, does the "Arrays must be same length" error persist?

Comment: @Felix, yes with youre help I fixed the Array Problem. Thank you very much (I appreciate it a lot)! Now I do have this output Problem!

Comment: Allright. That seems to me like a complete new question. Your editing is prety confusing to me. A SO Question should contain one specific problem with the code to reproduce it and a clear description of what is not working as expected and what is expected. What we have here now is a description of an (solved) problem with the code leading to it combined with the output that appears after fixing the problem and another vague desctiption of "this is still not what i whant". Please eddit the question to be clear or consider writing a new question for the new problem and link it so I can find it.

Comment: @Felix Ok is it now a bit less confusing?

Comment: OK, now at least your new problem is clear. I will look into it. But that problem now seems to be only related to your interpolation algorithm and has nothing to do any more with the title of the question, the code you provided (as this still produces the old problem) or any other content int this Q&A (the answer and comments). I really think it is best to post a second question which isolates the new problem. This also gives the oportunity to leave out any code/information that is not needed for the new problem.

Comment: I will do it! Thanks

Comment: Could you solve your ploblem? If so, please consider marking this question as solved to make it clear, no other anwers are neccessary.

Comment: @Felix, yeah I copied the code in a new file and than it works! How do I mark this question?

Comment: Great! That is good to hear! As for marking the question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) might be a good read. In short, to mark a question as solved, accept an answer by clicking the "tick" next to the question.

Comment: Also consider removing the `print(dfl)` output from the question and put the "Arrays must be same length" error text back in.

Answer (score 1):

Your global `grid` variable has different sizes for `grid["x"]` and `grid["y"]`. That is because `data["lats"]` in `genareate_grid` does not neccessarily span values with a difference of 360 between the min and max.

I suspect that your `inter_todf` does not do what it is meant to do. What you mostl likely want is each "line" containing a position in x-y with the according value. This requires something like:

```
x = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
y = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

What you try to print instead is:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 1, 2]
```